# python adding zeroes and a random digit in floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, floating-point

Trying to add zeroes and a random digit in floats in Python.

I have a code that just loops through and shows the cumulative frequency at each step and the final sum should be 1 but it isn't working.

Here is the output:

```
0.11
0.197
0.279
0.35700000000000004
0.43000000000000005
0.502
0.569
0.6299999999999999
0.6829999999999999
0.723
0.761
0.794
0.8240000000000001
0.8520000000000001
0.8790000000000001
0.9040000000000001
0.9270000000000002
0.9470000000000002
0.9630000000000002
0.9770000000000002
0.9870000000000002
0.9961000000000002
1.0005000000000002
1.0032
1.0056
1.0077
1.0077
```

I think this is being caused by the long row of zeroes in some numbers like **0.35700000000000004** in the 4th one. Also, many values are changing like in the first step it should be **0.11** and not **0.197**.

Example code:

```py
for i in AlphabetWeights:
    count = i+count
    print(count)
```

Comment: What is `AlphabetWeights` ?

Comment: @Laci it is a list 'weights' given to each alphabet in the English language depending on it's usage in dictionaries

Comment: I mean please provide a [mre], as mentioned by @KingOtto this is not an arithmetic issue, the error is far too big.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an arithmetic issue.. You can see that your truncation error is happening O(1e-16), as is expected. What you describe as an 'error' is on the order of 1e-3. You even see that your truncation error is cancelling out at times.. no way that your deviation of 0.0077 from the desired result 1.0 is due to floating-point arithmetic

> > like in the first step it should be 0.11 and not 0.197.

Check your code for bugs.. this is not floating-point arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Decimal` in this case. The decimal module provides support for fast correctly-rounded decimal floating-point arithmetic. Check this link: [Python Decimal](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-decimal/)

Check this code:

```py
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 6

Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')

getcontext().prec = 28

Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

for example:

```
x = 0.1
y = 0.1
z = 0.1

s = x + y + z

print(s)
```

the output will be :

```
0.30000000000000004
```

but

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal


x = Decimal('0.1')
y = Decimal('0.1')
z = Decimal('0.1')

s = x + y + z

print(s)
```

the output will be :

```
0.3
```

Comment: To add because I'm too lazy to write an actual answer: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html this explains in easy terms why float has errors. Worth quoting from it: "Note that this is in the very nature of binary floating-point: this is not a bug in Python, and it is not a bug in your code either."

Comment: not relevant here. The idea of 'floating point arithmetic' is a red herring - MrBlue's problem has nothing to do with truncation errors

Comment: my answer is not related to truncation. maybe you did not check it completely. it's about floating-point arithmetic

Comment: Re “it's about floating-point arithmetic”: The rounding errors of floating-point arithmetic do not account for an error of .0077 when adding 27 non-negative numbers whose real-arithmetic sum is near 1. Therefore, this answer does not explain the error. There must be some programming bug, and using decimal would not, by itself, fix the problem.